# How to decompose/parse 'in which + noun'?

Tags: pronouns, determiners, fused-determiner

> A sixth group that I joined consisted of women who made embroidered pictures and lived in a working-class neighborhood in Maud, in south-eastern Santiago, that was slightly too well-off to be called a shantytovm, and whose inhabitants did not think of themselves as living in a shantytown, and for these reasons I did not examine data from this group for the book.
>
> These groups accepted me as a participant observer, **in which role** I watched their work and helped as much as I could without changing what they normally did. I observed them for a year, except in the case of one of the groups of women from southern Santiago, which I observed for two months. Even though I concluded the participant observa-tion five years after Pinochet stepped down, the data gained were still pertinent to this book, as they enabled me to learn about the shantytowns and shantytown family life.

[Source:](http://books.google.com/books?id=-U5q-xtfsWMC&pg=PA13&dq=%22in+which+role+I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NYBHVMWfCMaxmAWpwoLwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22in%20which%20role%20I%22&f=false) p 13, *Surviving Dictatorship: A Work of Visual Sociology*
By Jacqueline Adams

Does **in which  + noun = a noun in which**? Even if so, more generally, what are the structures and syntax behind **in which + noun**? **in which** is a relative pronoun, right? So how can a **noun** follow it?

Comment: _Which_ is a relative pronoun. _In_ is a preposition. _In which <noun>_ is a prepositional phrase, not much different from "In which box the ball is, I am not going to tell you".

Comment: *In 1970, he met Smokin' Joe Johnson in the ring, in which fight he suffered a broken nose and a concussion.*  = *...a fight in which he suffered..."*

Answer (score 2):

*Which* in this case acts as an adjective/determiner, not as a pronoun. You may think of it as a relative counterpart to *this* or *that*:

> These groups accepted me as a participant observer. In **that** role I watched their work.

*Which* exhibits the same dual use as an interrogative:

> Which<sup>DET</sup> role did you play? ... Which<sup>PRO</sup> did Larry play?

Many determiners have this dual use:

> Many<sup>DET</sup> determiners have this dual use. ...  Many<sup>PRO</sup> have this dual use.
>   This<sup>DET</sup> pattern is common in English. ... This<sup>PRO</sup> is common in English.
>   What<sup>DET</sup> difficulty do you find here? ... What<sup>PRO</sup> do you find here?

Comment: Is " a participant observer. **which** role I watched **in** their work" correct?

Comment: @Dinusha No, that would mean that you looked at the role! What is meant by *in which role* is that you acted **in** the role just named (participant observer) and **in** that role you watched their work.

Comment: "a participant observer, in **whose** role I watched their work" and "a participant observer, **whose** role I watched in their work" aren't right?

Comment: @Dinusha No. *Whose* would tell us that the role belonged to the "participant observer", that the "participant observer" was the person who played it. But the "participant observer" ***is*** the role, played by ***I***; what ***I*** am talking about next is what I did specifically in ***that*** role.

Comment: Here,Is  _that_  a relative pronoun or a determiner ?

Comment: @Dinusha A determiner; in traditional grammar, a demonstrative adjective.

Comment: OK,I got it.I thought here _which_ and _that_ are used as relative pronouns which describe 'the participant observer'. thank you for replying!

Comment: Thank you. Would you please enlarge on your answer? I understand everything therein, but I still don't perceive how it connects/extends to **in which + noun**? How does **in that/this + noun** relate here?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @Dinusha Would you like to recast your comments into a new question and answer? I think that they're superlative but would be more organised in a new question.